# How to remove the temporary css codes

Tags: javascript, css, zoom-sdk, elementstyle

I need to disable the position: absolute; from the page
this code is showing as temporary and when i open the page.php or View page source in browser don't show any thing about this short css codes

so how i can delete it?

[image]

Comment: Do you still want the div to take up the left and top positions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rewrite the style prop on the element

```
document.querySelector('.zoomContainer').style.position = value
```

Comment: How to doing that can you explain please, i added it in the footer as 

<script>
document.querySelector('zoomContainer').style.position = unset;
</script>

Comment: document.querySelector('zoomContainer').style.position = '' but if this happens after the dom is rendered you will need use javascript but not inline, i dont know what you wanna do, but you can access the element and edit its props, you can try on console after page is loaded, but for more help besides what you ask I need more info

Comment: i have a store, in product page when open the category dropdown and going up to the product image the dropdown closing because of zoomin, so when i change the position from position: absolute; to position: unset; problem being resolve, but i can't found this style that is what i want to do

Comment: First try to find it on Dev console document.querySelector('zoomContainer'), if it returns the element try to change it in the console, if it works, you must put a event before dropdown is visible, so when you click on the button to show the dropdown you must call de document.querySelector('zoomContainer').style.position = 'unset' as you want, because probably every time that it happens the style reset to the original state, so you probably will need to do this on the dropdown event.

Comment: You can also try to see what class the dropdown puts as active state and set it on the .css as !important , some dropdowns put active, visible, some times both, so if you see you can get this class and put on a css file or you style head, #idDropDown.visible { position:unset!important;}